# Uniform index sampling for numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a space of zeros with a variable dimension and an array of ones with a variable dimension, for instance:

```
import numpy    

space = numpy.zeros((1000,5))
a = numpy.ones((150))
```

I would like to insert the ones of the array inside the matrix in order that those ones will be homogeneously distributed inside the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.linspace` to obtain the indices.

It's not obvious if you'd like to assign a slice of five ones to every index location or just assign to the first index of the slice. This is how both of these would work:

```
space = numpy.zeros((1000,5))
a = numpy.ones((150, 5))
b = numpy.ones((150,))

index = numpy.rint(numpy.linspace(start=0, stop=999, num=150)).astype(np.int)

# This would assign five ones to every location
space[index] = a

# This would assign a one to the first element at every location
space[index, 0] = b
```